# Upgrade of Angular version 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to upgrade my Angular version from 5 to 6 using the commands shown here, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6
npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/core@6
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What happens instead? Are you facing any error message?

Comment: I am not getting any error.. for angular cli I am getting warning that my global version (6.2.9) is higher than local version(1.7.4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple options, either update your `package.json` with the specific version you want to use and run `npm install` to install that latest version or run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6  //globally
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@6  
ng update @angular/core@6
```

Comment: I am getting warning that my global version (6.2.9) is higher than local version(1.7.4).

Comment: I want to upgrade it specifically for angular version 6. If I am not wrong then 3rd and 4th command will upgrade it to latest version than the one which we want

Comment: You means to say      npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6 --save-dev
npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/core@6 --save-dev

Comment: No, check updated answer, you just need to update your local version of angular/cli right?

Comment: gotcha npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@6

Comment: will the core version too update with  this command i have just replaced cli with core ?npm install --save-dev @angular/core@6

Comment: My local cli upgraded to 6.1 but my global too upgraded to 12.2.6 don't know why

Comment: if you only care about your application being v6 and not globally then just run `ng update @angular/cli@6 @angular/core@6` or update it in your package.json then rerun npm install like I mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: You mean update the package.json manually ?

Comment: Yes, like I said earlier, if you only care about the version for your application/local the solutions I provided above should do it. Still unclear what you're trying to solve.

Comment: ng update @angular/cli@6 @angular/core@6 command doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: I am trying to do upgrade my angular version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239583/discussion-between-stoobish-and-bhushan-khaladkar).